# How to calculate database column statistics given the table and column name?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that accepts a (SQL Server) database table, and returns a summary of each column.

Most of what I want is available from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`, but for numeric columns I'd like to include some some basic statistics such as mean/min/max.

My plan was to have a query like this:

```
SELECT
    TABLE_NAME,
    COLUMN_NAME,
    DATA_TYPE AS DataType,
    CASE 
      WHEN DATA_TYPE IN (
        'bigint', 'bit', 'date', 'datetime', 'datetime2',
        'datetimeoffset', 'decimal', 'float', 'int', 'money', 
        'numeric', 'real', 'smalldatetime', 'smallint', 'smallmoney', 
        'time', 'timestamp', 'tinyint')
        THEN dbo.GetMin(TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME)
      ELSE NULL
    END AS MinSql
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

And a user-defined function `GetMin`, the whose body looked like this:

```
DECLARE @Sql varchar(MAX) = CONCAT(
  'SELECT MIN(', 
  @ColumnName, 
  ') FROM ', 
  @TableName
  ''';'
);

EXEC(@Sql);
```

Unfortunately, calls to `EXEC` are not permitted inside UDFs.

How do I either:

1. Return a statistics like `MIN`, given the table name and column name, or
2. Loop over all columns taking the `MIN` (and other stats)?

Comment: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from the **"Common Cases when to (Not) Use Dynamic SQL"** heading of the
 [article from my comment](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Common_cases),

> A common question is why the following does not work:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc @tablename sysname AS
   SELECT * FROM @tablename
```

> As we have seen, we can make this procedure work with help of dynamic
>   SQL, but it should also be clear that we gain none of the advantages
>   with generating that dynamic SQL in a stored procedure. You could just
>   as well send the dynamic SQL from the client. So, OK: 1) if the SQL
>   statement is very complex, you save some network traffic and you do
>   encapsulation. 2) As we have seen, starting with SQL 2005 there are
>   methods to deal with permissions. Nevertheless, this **is** a bad idea.

Comment: Let me make sure I've understood this correctly.  Using dynamic SQL to summarise an arbitrary table is bad.  There are no tools like stored procedures, functions or anything else that will make it acceptable.  If I were to generate the SQL using another programming language, and execute the SQL from there, it would be OK.  Having many similar stored procedures, one for each table, would also be acceptable.

Comment: @RichieCotton To condense, stored procedures are really good for repeating queries that benefit from a cached query plan. If the parameters you pass radically effect the structure of the query, the cached query plan is overhead at best. You'd be better off passing your parameterized query to `sp_executesql` which will benefit when the query happens to be the same. You'll note, this is what much of the code in the .Net framework and Entity Framework does under the hood.